# Meaning of "default" in "iface default inet dhcp" in interfaces file

Tags: networking, configuration, interface

My `/etc/network/interfaces` file contains the line:

```
iface default inet dhcp
```

I vaguely remember putting it in there years ago, but I don't remember why I did so.
If I am not mistaken, `iface` precedes a network interface configuration, `inet` stipulates ipv4 address specs, and `dhcp` means: get your address, mask, and gateway info from a DHCP server. But what does `default` mean in this case? Does it refer to some default interface? If so, where would such a thing be specified? If not, does it refer to a default configuration that applies to all existing interfaces not otherwise configured? Generally, what is the purpose, if any, of such a line?

When I remove the line in question my computer seems to keep on connecting to networks just fine.

I looked at man interfaces and googled quite a bit, but I have been unable, so far, to find any official explanation for the use of default in this case.

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name "default" is just a place holder and can be used to specify how a interface should be loaded.

```
#auto eth0=foo
iface foo inet dhcp

iface bar inet static
address 192.168.178.2
gateway 192.168.178.1
dns-nameserver 192.168.178.1
...
```

then you could call the interface like this ...

```
ifup eth0=bar
```

There are many configurations possible this way. Have a look in your `man interfaces` and `man ifup`.

Comment: Thanks. If understand you correctly, I could then do ifup eth0=default and eth0 would be loaded using inet dhcp?

Comment: yes sir, as long the interface isn't in use already.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you entry:

```
iface default inet dhcp
```

is at the end of your config file (after the definition of eth0, wlan...).
That line is the default config in case of none of the definition above fit with your hardware config

Comment: Thank you - Yes, it is at the end. So if I were to install a new interface, then this entry should help configure it? Let me test by removing the lines specific to my Ethernet card and see if it still loads. I'll report back.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, iface default inet dhcp did not load a usb to ethernet plugin network interface (which does load when the appropriate entries are in the interfaces file). I could not test my built in ethernet card because it has on of those unfortunate mini-ports, for which I currently have no cable. BTW, I tried adding the line allow-hotplug default, and it didn't work either.